# blank jframe when trying to implement javafx into swing

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I've created a basic javafx fxml which works well when lauching directly in an *extends Application* but I'm trying to implement it into a JFrame. But when I launch it, the entire JFrame is blank. Just white.

This is my current code:

```
public class MainDisplay extends JFrame {
    private Core core;
    public MainDisplay(Core core) {
        this.core=core;
        create();
    }

    JFXPanel jfxPanel;

    private void create() {
        core.logger.log(getClass(), "Creating main display...");
        jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        setSize(1280, 720);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 720));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Platform.runLater(this::createFxScene);

        add(jfxPanel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createFxScene() {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("layout.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 720);
            jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            core.logger.error(getClass(), "Failed to load MainFxScene....");
        }
    }
}
```

I know that it finds the layout.fxml file through a debugger so it's not that. Anything helps :)

Comment: *"I've created a basic javafx fxml which works well .. but I'm trying to implement it into a JFrame."* ... ***Why?***

Comment: @AndrewThompson I know Swing for usability but just decided to make the visuals in JavaFX becuase swing looks and feels ancient.

Comment: *"I know Swing for usability"* It becomes a lot less usable (or at least, harder to program) when mixing it with components from another toolkit that run on their own thread. I reckon it'd be faster to learn how to make the app. 100% Java-FX, but if you want to pursue this, good luck with it. It's not something I'd devote time to helping.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you provide, perhaps I missed it or perhaps the error is in the code you don't provide.  Run the test program which Oracle provided in ["Integrating JavaFX into Swing Applications"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm).  Make sure it works in your environment, then make small modifications to it to get it to perform the functionality you want, testing to make sure each small modification works before proceeding.

Comment: @jewelsea Ran the example code in the link, all fine. Made a few adjustments and ran the code each adjustment and it only broke when I got rid of the text and replaced the **Group root = new Group();** with **Parent root = Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(MainDisplay.class.getResource("layout.fxml"));**
It definitely knows the layout file is there bc I've test debugged it. I really can't tell what's going on here.

Comment: For more help post [mre]